# Cannot install pip3. apt says I have it, but I can't find it

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install some pip packages on an Ubuntu 18.4 (For python3) I see if pip is even installed

```
>/home/me/pip3
Command 'pip3' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

So I do that and I get this:

```
>/home/me/sudo apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
```

I try whereis for pip:

```
>/home/me/whereis pip
pip: /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 /opt/jython2.7.0/bin/pip /opt/jython2.7.0/bin/pip2.7
```

and for pip3:

```
>/home/me/whereis pip3
pip3: /usr/share/man/man1/pip3.1.gz
```

Why do I have the man pages for it?  This makes no sense to me.  Any Ideas?

**UPDATE**

In answer to the first 3 comments
@Mad Physicist  Yes it's in my path, and version get's me:

```
pip 19.0.3 from /home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Why is it there?

@KuboMD  I get this:

```
 >/home/me/python -m pip install xyz
 Collecting xyz
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xyz (from versions: )
 No matching distribution found for xyz
```

@amitr  I get this:

```
>/home/me/which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

but that one in my usr/local/bin

Comment: What do you get from just `where pip`? Is `/usr/local/bin` on your PATH? What does `pip --version` show?

Comment: Does `python -m pip install xyz` work?

Comment: To look for an executable file use `which` - in your case, `which pip3`. On my system (Debian, should be very similar to Ubuntu) it is in `/usr/bin/pip3`. Is `/usr/bin` in you PATH? Last thing, `whereis` will look for executables if you call it with `-b` switch. Look at `man whereis`.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, on a Debian or Ubuntu system, you should either use `apt` to install Python packages or use `pip`, but don't try to mix the two. One possible way forward from this mess would be to create a new venv to do all your work in, and use `pip` inside the venv to install all your dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you `pip --version` output, I assume you have made some upgrades to pip, probably using `pip install --upgrade pip --user` command, because `19.0.3` is the version you get when upgrading `pip` via `pip`. On Ubuntu, both pip2 and pip3 have package version `9.0.1` as you can see here:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3-pip

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-pip

It appears that location of your `pip` is `/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip`. This is where python programs/modules end up, when they are installed via `pip install --user` option. From that `--version` output, you can see that your current default `pip` is actually `pip3` because version outputs that it's for `(python 3.6)`, i.e. pip that installs packages for python3.6.

Try listing what other `pip` binaries you have in your `/home/me/.local/bin` with command:

```
ls /home/me/.local/bin/pip*
```

You should see `pip3` and probably `pip3.6` there as well.

If there is `pip3` executable there a solution would be adding `/home/me/.local/` to you PATH environment variable, so that `pip3` is callable directly from your shell.

Comment: pip install --upgrade pip --user,  that's exactly what I did,  thank you!